# How to configure NAR Maven projects?

Tags: c++, maven, pom.xml

I am trying to *Mavenize* a C++ project with nar-maven, on Windows with MSVC. It is a shared library.
 
I already tested successfully nar-maven on sample projects with this [archetype](https://github.com/duns/maven-archetype-nar-lib).

So now, I need to use the [nar-maven-plugin](http://maven-nar.github.io/index.html) for a bigger project. In order to compile successfully, I need to add some arguments (includes, libs, preprocessor definitions...). And this is where I am stuck. Here is a sample of my current pom file :

```
<project>

  ...

  <properties>
    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
  </properties>  

  <build>
    <defaultGoal>integration-test</defaultGoal>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.github.maven-nar</groupId>
        <artifactId>nar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.0</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
          <options>
              <option>/D_WINDOWS</option>
              <option>/D_WINDLL</option>
              <option>...</option>
          </options>
          <libraries>
            <library>
              <type>shared</type>
            </library>
          </libraries>
          <tests>
            <test>
              <name>libblawin</name>
              <link>shared</link>
            </test>
          </tests>

        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    ...
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Whatever parameter I add (options tag, includes tag...) within the configuration tag, it is not taken in account by maven. Indeed, when I look for the command line used to compile a source file (using the -X option with mvn) the options added in the pom.xml are not included.
The command line used by maven :

```
Executing 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\amd64\cl' with arguments:
''
'/c'
'/nologo'
'/EHsc'
'/DNDEBUG'
'/MD'
'/GR'
'/FdD:\NAR-projects\srt\target\nar\obj\amd64-Windows-msvc\'
'/DWIN32'
'/ID:\NAR-projects\srt\target\nar\obj\amd64-Windows-msvc'
'/ID:\NAR-projects\srt\target\nar\obj\amd64-Windows-msvc'
'/ID:\NAR-projects\srt\src\main\include'
'/IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include'
'/IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\include'
'/IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\shared'
'/IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um'
'/IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\winrt'
'/FoD:\NAR-projects\srt\target\nar\obj\amd64-Windows-msvc\libraryExtern.1d1757c3.obj'
'include/interapp/libraryExtern.cpp'
```

Anyway, I think that I am doing something wrong, and I hope you can help. I need to find a way to configure my project as I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured.

I browsed the [working examples](https://github.com/maven-nar/nar-maven-plugin/wiki/Working-examples) in order to see where my mistake was, and on this particular example, [imagej-launcher](https://github.com/imagej/imagej-launcher/blob/imagej-launcher-4.0.5/pom.xml#L145-L172), we can see that it adds all the compiler configuration inside a **c tag** :

```
            <configuration>
                <c>
                    <name>gcc</name>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*.c</include>
                    </includes>
                    <options>
                            <option>-DLAUNCHER_VERSION="${project.version}"</option>
                            <option>-DBUILD_NUMBER="${buildNumber}"</option>
                            <option>-I${JAVA_HOME}/include</option>
                            <option>${java.os.include}</option>
                            <option>${stack.protector.option}</option>
                            <option>${architecture.option}</option>
                            <option>${subsystem.option}</option>
                            <option>${debug.option}</option>
                    </options>
               </c>
             ...
```

So I just added a **cpp** tag and put my options in it, and now it works fine :

```
    <configuration>
      <cpp>
          <options>
              <option>/D_WINDOWS</option>
              <option>/D_WINDLL</option>
              <option>...</option>
          </options>
      </cpp>
```